# Failed to push selection: Read-only file system error .How do i solve this error?

Tags: android, eclipse

I use eclipse 4.4.2

The error shows up everytime I try to push an image file into the /mt/sd/

I tried making the Users/.android as non read-only

I opened AVD manager and tried to edit but there is no hardware options as people had suggested

Also after adding the permissions in manifest file ,the problem seems to prevail

how do i solve this error ? Also,is there any other way to add an image without going through this difficult process?

Comment: have you added WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in manifest? post your manifest code

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application .............

Comment: Also the emulator is displaying a message " Process system isn't responding"..but it was working just fine till yesterday